# Count all files in folder and subfolder + folders that says 0 files

Tags: powershell, networking, cmd, directory, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to run a Powershell command or CMD command, that count all files in 1 folder and its subfolder. I got a script that count all files, but it does not find hidden files. The problem I found was in my network share there was a folder that said 0 files, but when I go into the folder there are a lot of files in there.

Is there a way to get those files into the count?

I have tried a few Powershell command and CMD commands.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

I can only get it to count files Windows can see, if a folder says 0 files but there are files in there, it does not count it.

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force`

Comment: sometimes even the `-Force` parameter won't let you see files. you can't see what you don't have permission to see. another is such situation is when you have files with special filesystem wildcard characters [square brackets, for instance] in the path or filename UNLESS you use `-LiteralPath` instead of the default `-Path`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the force

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
16
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test  -Force | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
17
```

The -Force parameter on Get-ChildItem will force inclusion of hidden files